# Highchart displaying only part of the Y-axis labels in Firefox/Win

Tags: highcharts, label

In Firefox 44.0 Windows, part of the labels on the y-axis don't appear; instead a "..." is being displayed. I have tested the page in several other browsers where it works fine ([here is a link](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/extras/arctic_sea_ice_graph_heatmap.php)). Looks like this:

[image]

I'd say there is enough space for writing the whole four numbers - that is years, instead of "19...".

Any idea what I can do about it?

Comment: That is weird! Because when I look at your website in Firefox (44.0.2) Windows, I do not see the behavior as you mentioned. 
Did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: Agree with @Rotan075 , its working well in Firefox 43.0.4 as well

Comment: I am also not able to recreate your issue. Maybe adding
textOverflow: 'none' inside your yAxis labels style will help you avoid this ellipsis? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.style

Comment: Strange. 44.0.2, and still the same thing... But great, if everybody else doesn't experience this problem... :-) Thanks for the feedback!